# Fuzzy search with stop words produces unexpected results with Lucene / ElasticSearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am noticing that the fuzzy operator on stop words does not produce the results I'd expect.

Here's my configuration:

```
index :
    analysis :
        analyzer :
            my_analyzer :
                tokenizer : my_tokenizer
                filter : [standard, my_stop_english_filter]

        tokenizer :
            my_tokenizer :
                type : standard
                max_token_length : 512

        filter :
            my_stop_english_filter :
                type : stop
                stopwords : [the]
                ignore_case : true
```

And suppose I have indexed:
    **the brown fox**

If I search for:
  **the brown~ fox~**, then I get a hit as expected.

However, if I search for: **the~ brown~ fox~**, then I do not get a hit, presumably because the fuzzy operator prevents **the** from being treated as a stop word.

Is there a way I can combine stop words with fuzzy search?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: What do you expect as the results of *the~ brown~ fox~*

Comment: I'd expect to be able to find *the brown fox*.  But because of the fuzzy operator, the stop word *the* is not being treated as a stop word (I think).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this is the way Lucene is supposed to work as it is currently written -- using a fuzzy search disable the stopping of the stop words. It would take some work, but you could create a modified version of the query parser so stop words are ignored when applying fuzzy search (but then how do handle a fuzzy search on something that looks like a stop word?)